# Normalize user rating

Tags: average, percentages

I have set of ratings on scale of 1 to 5. To calculate the percentage of ratings, I have used the following formula

> (average rating-minimum rating)/(max rating - min rating)

What does this kind of formula called in mathematics?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth standardization usually means something different in statistics

Comment: 'Normalize' is not uncommon. However I would still explain the term before using it.